# RAM Limited to 256MB while 4GB installed

Tags: ubuntu, memory, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge 800 running, with 4 1GB RAM modules installed, totaling 4GB. But while doing POST, it displays a message saying "Amount of Memory Limited to 256MB" and checking System Monitor in Ubuntu (Ubuntu Jaunty Jackalope) the OS also reports 256MB in total.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 15):

This is on the [Dell forums](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/3940745.aspx):

> In the BIOS disable "OS Install Mode"

As ome background: Some older operating systems failed to install on systems with (for their time) absurd amounths of memory. Temporarily limiting the amount of available memory until the OS was installed and updated was a workaround.

Answer (score -2):

Pull the CMOS battery on the system board while the server power cord is unplugged. This worked for me in a PE1650 with the exact same issue, not 100% it will work for this system but worth a try.